# disable access via http to my docker containers

Tags: docker, nginx, debian

I am trying to set a debian server where I have multiple apps running in **docker** containers each on has it's own **port**.

Lets suppose that it's IP is (**160.160.160.160**) linked to a domain example160.com
and two apps (two docker containers) running on **5500** and **6600**

I have also set some reverse proxy configs so I can acces to the apps via subdomains like **app5500.example160.com** and **app6600.example160.com**.
Here's an example of one of the configs

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    server_name app5500.example160.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:80/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding gzip;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example160.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example160.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app5500.example160.com;
    
    if ($host = app5500.example160.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

as you can see I did a redirection from http to https and that's working only if I try to access to http://app5500.example160.com but the issue is that I am still able to access to container via urls such as http://www.example160.com:5500 and http://160.160.160.160:5500 and I dont know how to block it in order to access to the container only via https://app5500.example160.com

I tried this solution but adding this other nginx config to redirect other subdomain but it's not working

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name *.example160.com;

    if ($host !~ ^example160\.com$) {
        return 301 https://example160.com$request_uri;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example160.com-0001/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example160.com-0001/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    return 404;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name *.example160.com;

    return 301 https://example160.com$request_uri;
}
```

I tried even to set up a firewall with iptables and nftables but I ended up with no firewall installed because they didnt help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than publishing your container ports on all interfaces, bind them to localhost instead:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:5500:5500 ...
```

This way they will *only* be accessible to your nginx proxy; there will be no way to connect to the port directly from a remote location.

---

Or, run your proxy in a container (if you're not doing that already), and then there's no need to publish the container ports **at all**. The proxy would be able to connect to the containers directly because they would be running on the same internal network.

You would only need to publish the proxy port(s).